# how to assign null to a field in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to assign `null` to a field in SQLite but am not getting anywhere with this:

```
update t set n=null where n=0;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error you get?

Comment: don't get an error, but nothing happens.

Comment: Please add to your question: 1) The schema of your table, 2) some exaple data that already is in the table.

Comment: are there any n==0 rows?

Comment: @nawfal If not, it would cause an error: `Error: t.n may not be NULL`

Comment: If you haven't got an answer thats ok; the question is simple enough and schema + data are trivial. all these comments are noise, not signal - reminds me of usenet.

Comment: @mrcalendar your code should work. Show the schema and values to help better. Answer Marcus question

Comment: @mrcalendar If schema and data are trivial, please add them to your question.

Answer (score 17):

I can not reproduce your problem. From what you write, I guess your table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (n integer);
```

Inserting data:

```
insert into t values (1);
insert into t values (2);
insert into t values (3);
insert into t values (0);
```

Updating the data with your `UPDATE`:

```
update t set n = null where n = 0;
```

Now the table looks like this:

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE t (n integer);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(NULL);
COMMIT;
```

There might be no output after the `UPDATE` but it has the desired effect.